# Cloud9 IDE Heroku Login

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt, cloud9

I need help logging into Heroku from Cloud9 IDE.

In a cloud9 IDE terminal, I enter `heroku login` and I don't get the chance to enter any credentials.

Instead I get the following
`heroku: Press any kety to open up the browser to login or q to exit:`

I hit any key and get the following:
`heroku: Waiting for login...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the latest update, this shall work:

```
heroku login -i
```

Comment: That was the answer.  I didn't see this update documented.  Thanks for the find.

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer seems possible, as Heroku now requires MFA which does not allow access through heroku login -i or heroku login --interactive

Answer (score 0):

You will need to access Heroku using an API key, which is found on the https://dashboard.heroku.com/account page.